# Creating Capacity Overflowed Exception

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I am trying to develop and implement a CapacityErrorException that detects and throws an exception if the unified array set exceeds the capacity amount of the array set. I will provide my function where I would like to create the capacity error exception along with my class to show what I am trying to do. Any help or guidance in the right direction would be appreciated.

Here is my function setUnion:

```
    template <class ItemType>
    ArraySet<ItemType> ArraySet <ItemType> ::setUnion(const ArraySet<ItemType> set2)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < getCurrentSize(); i++)
        {
            unionSet.add(items[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < set2.getCurrentSize(); i++)
        {
            unionSet.add(set2.items[i]);
            if (items[i] == set2.items[i])
                unionSet.remove(set2.items[i]);
        }


        return unionSet;
    }
```

Here is my class:

```
// @file ArrayBag.h */

#ifndef ARRAY_SET_
#define ARRAY_SET_
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include "SetInterface.h"

namespace cs_set {
    template<class ItemType>
    class ArraySet : public SetInterface<ItemType>
    {
        public:
            typedef ItemType value_type;
    
            class DuplicateItemError {};
            class ItemNotFoundError {};
            class CapacityExceededError {};
    
            ArraySet();
            int getCurrentSize() const;
            bool isEmpty() const;
            void add(const ItemType& newEntry);
            void remove(const ItemType& anEntry);
            void clear();
            bool contains(const ItemType& anEntry) const;
            ArraySet<ItemType> setUnion(const ArraySet<ItemType> set2);
            ArraySet<ItemType> setIntersection(const ArraySet<ItemType> set2);
            ArraySet<ItemType> setDifference(const ArraySet<ItemType> set2);
            //int getFrequencyOf(const ItemType& anEntry) const;
            std::vector<ItemType> toVector() const;
        private:
            static const int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 6;
            ItemType items[DEFAULT_CAPACITY];
            int itemCount;
            int maxItems;

            // Returns either the index of the element in the array items that
            // contains the given target or -1, if the array does not contain 
            // the target.
            int getIndexOf(const ItemType& target) const;   
    };
}

#include "ArraySet.cpp"
#endif
```

Derived class file:

```
#ifndef SET_INTERFACE
#define SET_INTERFACE

#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

namespace cs_set {
    template<class ItemType>
    class SetInterface
    {
    public:
       /** Gets the current number of entries in this bag.
        @return  The integer number of entries currently in the bag. */
       virtual int getCurrentSize() const = 0;

       /** Sees whether this bag is empty.
        @return  True if the bag is empty, or false if not. */
       virtual bool isEmpty() const = 0;

       /** Adds a new entry to this bag.
        @post  If successful, newEntry is stored in the bag and
           the count of items in the bag has increased by 1.
        @param newEntry  The object to be added as a new entry.
        @return  True if addition was successful, or false if not. */
       virtual void add(const ItemType& newEntry) = 0;

       /** Removes one occurrence of a given entry from this bag,
           if possible.
        @post  If successful, anEntry has been removed from the bag
           and the count of items in the bag has decreased by 1.
        @param anEntry  The entry to be removed.
        @return  True if removal was successful, or false if not. */
       virtual void remove(const ItemType& anEntry) = 0;

       /** Removes all entries from this bag.
        @post  Bag contains no items, and the count of items is 0. */
       virtual void clear() = 0;

       /** Counts the number of times a given entry appears in this bag.
        @param anEntry  The entry to be counted.
        @return  The number of times anEntry appears in the bag. */
      // virtual int getFrequencyOf(const ItemType& anEntry) const = 0;

       /** Tests whether this bag contains a given entry.
        @param anEntry  The entry to locate.
        @return  True if bag contains anEntry, or false otherwise. */
       virtual bool contains(const ItemType& anEntry) const = 0;

       /** Empties and then fills a given vector with all entries that
           are in this bag.
        @return  A vector containing all the entries in the bag. */
       virtual std::vector<ItemType> toVector() const = 0;

       /** Destroys this bag and frees its assigned memory. (See C++ Interlude 2.) */
       virtual ~SetInterface() { }
    };
}
#endif
```

namespace file:

```
namespace cs_set {

    template<class ItemType>
    void ArraySet<ItemType>::add(const ItemType& newEntry) {
        //auto result1 = std::find(std::begin(items), std::end(items), newEntry);
        //int locatedIndex = getIndexOf(new);
        if (std::find(std::begin(items), std::end(items), newEntry) != std::end(items))
       {
            throw DuplicateItemError();
       }  
        else 
       {  
            items[itemCount] = newEntry;
            itemCount++;
       }  
    }  




    template<class ItemType>
    ArraySet<ItemType>::ArraySet() {
        itemCount = 0;
        maxItems = DEFAULT_CAPACITY;
    }





    template<class ItemType>
    int ArraySet<ItemType>::getCurrentSize() const {
        return itemCount;
    }





    template<class ItemType>
    bool ArraySet<ItemType>::isEmpty() const {
        return itemCount == 0;
    }




    template<class ItemType>
    std::vector<ItemType> ArraySet<ItemType>::toVector() const {
        std::vector<ItemType> setContents;
        for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
            setContents.push_back(items[i]);
        }
  
        return setContents;
    }




    template <class ItemType>
    bool ArraySet<ItemType>::contains(const ItemType& anEntry) const {
        bool isFound = false;
        int curIndex = 0;
        while (!isFound && (curIndex < itemCount)) {
            isFound = (anEntry == items[curIndex]);
            if (!isFound) {
                curIndex++;
            }
        }

        return isFound;
    }






    template<class ItemType>
    void ArraySet<ItemType>::clear() {
        itemCount = 0;
    }





    template<class ItemType>
    int ArraySet<ItemType>::getIndexOf(const ItemType& target) const {
        bool isFound = false;
        int result = -1;
        int searchIndex = 0;

        while (!isFound && (searchIndex < itemCount)) {
            isFound = (items[searchIndex] == target);
            if (isFound) {
                result = searchIndex;
            } else {
                searchIndex++;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }






    template<class ItemType>
    void ArraySet<ItemType>::remove(const ItemType& anEntry) {
        int locatedIndex = getIndexOf(anEntry);
        if (locatedIndex > -1) {
            itemCount--;
            items[locatedIndex] = items[itemCount];
        } else {
            throw ItemNotFoundError();
        }
    }






    /*
    template<class ItemType>
    int ArraySet<ItemType>::getFrequencyOf(
                                                const ItemType& anEntry) const {
        int frequency = 0;
        int curIndex = 0;
        while (curIndex < itemCount) {
            if (items[curIndex] == anEntry) {
                frequency++;
            }

            curIndex++;
        }

        return frequency;
    }

    */


    template <class ItemType>
    ArraySet<ItemType> ArraySet <ItemType> ::setUnion(const ArraySet<ItemType> set2)
    {
        ArraySet<ItemType> unionSet;
        /*
        if (itemCount >= maxItems) {
            throw CapacityExceededError();
        } else {
            //items[itemCount] = newEntry;
            itemCount++;
        }  
        */
        for (int i = 0; i < getCurrentSize(); i++)
        {
            unionSet.add(items[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < set2.getCurrentSize(); i++)
        {
            unionSet.add(set2.items[i]);
            if (items[i] == set2.items[i])
                unionSet.remove(set2.items[i]);
        }

        /*
        // Add my items, removing dupes.

        for (int i = 0; i < getCurrentSize(); i++)
            if (!unionSet.contains(set2.items[i]))
                unionSet.add(items[i]);

        // Add other items, removing dupes.

        for (int i = 0; i < set2.getCurrentSize(); i++)
            if (!unionSet.contains(set2.items[i]))
                unionSet.add(set2.items[i]);
                */
        return unionSet;
    }


    template <class ItemType>
    ArraySet<ItemType> ArraySet<ItemType>::setIntersection(const ArraySet<ItemType> set2)
    {
        ArraySet<ItemType> interSet;

        for (int i = 0; i < getCurrentSize(); i++)
        {
            if (set2.contains(items[i]))
                interSet.add(items[i]);

        }

        return interSet;
    }

    template<class ItemType>
    ArraySet<ItemType> ArraySet<ItemType>::setDifference(const ArraySet<ItemType> set2)
    {
        ArraySet<ItemType> diffSet;

        for (int i = 0; i < getCurrentSize(); i++)
        {


            if (!set2.contains(items[i]))
                diffSet.add(items[i]);
        }



        return diffSet;
    }
}
```

Main file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "ArraySet.h"

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using namespace cs_set;

void displaySet(ArraySet<string>& set) {
   cout << "The set contains " << set.getCurrentSize()
        << " items:" << endl;
   std::vector<string> setItems = set.toVector();

   int numEntries = setItems.size();
   for (int i = 0; i < numEntries; i++) {
      cout << setItems[i] << " ";
   }
   cout << endl << endl;
}




void setTester(ArraySet<string>& set)
{
    const int LIMIT = 3;
    ArraySet<string> set1;
    ArraySet<string> set2;
    ArraySet<string> set3;
    ArraySet<string> intersection;
    ArraySet<string> difference;
    cout << "isEmpty: returns " << set.isEmpty()
         << "; should be 1 (true)" << endl;
    displaySet(set);

    std::string items[] = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "one"};
    cout << "Add 6 items to the set: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    
        try {
            set.add(items[i]);
            cout << items[i] << endl;
        }
        catch (ArraySet<string>::DuplicateItemError e)
        {
            //set.add(items[i]);
            cout << "IT IS A DUPLICATE!" << endl;
        }
    }

    displaySet(set);

    cout << "isEmpty: returns " << set.isEmpty()
         << "; should be 0 (false)" << endl;

    displaySet(set);

    cout << endl;

    std::string items1[] = { "one", "two", "three" };
    cout << "Add 3 items to the set1: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < LIMIT; i++)
    {
        try {
            set1.add(items1[i]);
            cout << items1[i] << endl;
        }
        catch (ArraySet<string>::DuplicateItemError e)
        {
            //set.add(items[i]);
            cout << "IT IS A DUPLICATE!" << endl;
        }
    }  // end for


    cout << endl;

    std::string items2[] = { "four", "five", "six" };
    cout << "Add 3 items to the set2: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < LIMIT; i++)
    {
        try {
            set2.add(items2[i]);
            cout << items2[i] << endl;
        }
        catch (ArraySet<string>::DuplicateItemError e)
        {
            //set.add(items[i]);
            cout << "IT IS A DUPLICATE!" << endl;
        }
    }  // end for
    cout << "\nset1: " << endl;
    displaySet(set1);
    cout << "set2: " << endl;
    displaySet(set2);


    set3 = set1.setUnion(set2);

    displaySet(set3);
    /*
    try {
        set1 = set2.setUnion(set3);
    }
    catch (ArraySet<string>::CapacityExceededError e) {
        cout << "Operation exceeds the capacity of sets and therefore failed." << endl;
    }
    */

    /*
    cout << "getCurrentSize: returns " << set.getCurrentSize()
         << "; should be 6" << endl;
         */

    /*
    try {
        cout << "Try to add another entry: add(\"extra\")... ";
        set.add("extra");
        cout << "should cause exception but didn't" << endl;
    } catch (ArraySet<string>::DuplicateItemError e) {
        cout << "should cause exception and did!" << endl;
    } */

    /*
    cout << "contains(\"three\"): returns " << set.contains("three")
         << "; should be 1 (true)" << endl;
    cout << "contains(\"ten\"): returns " << set.contains("ten")
         << "; should be 0 (false)" << endl;
    cout << "getFrequencyOf(\"one\"): returns "
         << set.getFrequencyOf("one") << " should be 2" << endl;

    try {
        cout << "remove(\"one\")... ";
        set.remove("one");
        cout << "shouldn't cause exception and didn't!" << endl;
    } catch (ArraySet<string>::ItemNotFoundError e) {
        cout << "shouldn't cause exception but did." << endl;
    }

    cout << "getFrequencyOf(\"one\"): returns "
         << set.getFrequencyOf("one") << " should be 1" << endl;
     
    try {
        cout << "remove(\"one\")... ";
        set.remove("one");
        cout << "shouldn't cause exception and didn't!" << endl;
    } catch (ArraySet<string>::ItemNotFoundError e) {
        cout << "shouldn't cause exception but did." << endl;
    }

    try {
        cout << "remove(\"one\")... ";
        set.remove("one");
        cout << "should cause exception but didn't" << endl;
    } catch (ArraySet<string>::ItemNotFoundError e) {
        cout << "should cause exception and did!" << endl;
    }
    cout << endl; 

    */

    //displaySet(set);

    /*
    cout << "After clearing the set, ";
    set.clear();
    cout << "isEmpty: returns " << set.isEmpty()
         << "; should be 1 (true)" << endl;

         */
}





int main()
{
    /*
    bool returnFromUnion;
    const int LIMIT = 3;
    ArraySet<string> set1;
    ArraySet<string> set2;
    ArraySet<string> set3;
    ArraySet<string> intersection;
    ArraySet<string> difference;
    */

    ArraySet<string> set;
    cout << "Testing the Array-Based Set:" << endl;
    cout << "The initial set is empty." << endl;
    setTester(set);

    cout << "All done!" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Why is your header file including `.cpp` code? That is a huge mistake. Any file that includes that header is going to get slammed with implementation code as well, and the compiler is not going to be happy.

Comment: @tadman its a way to make it compile in visual studio by excluding the cpp file. At least how I successfully compile multi file programs.

Comment: That's an extraordinarily ugly habit to get into. You should set up a proper build environment and not mess around with dark voodoo like that.

Comment: Where does `unionSet` come from?

Comment: Comes from my derived class included in my question in a namespace titled cs_set

Comment: It should be a local variable, and it isn't shown, or it's somewhere else? That union algorithm also fails to properly detect duplicates. You need to compare what you're about to insert to *every value* first, then skip the insert if it's already there. You're checking versus the same value in the same spot(??).

Comment: @churill After the merging operation, presumably, as they could be identical sets, which means no new data.

Comment: @churill yes indeed when the sets would overflow

Comment: @BrandonLuna Note [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file) please. If you want to separate Template implementations from their definitions in an extra source file, don't use `cpp` as file extension, this will lead to various problems (the Q&A in the link describes better ways). Also note: If you want a review of fully working and implemented code, [SE Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is the better site for this than SO.

Comment: Since you're doing C++ code you may want to implement these operations as `operator` overrides, like `operator+` for combining the two (union), or `operator|` for (union + unique). That makes it easy to do things like `set3 = set1 | set2` versus the far more clunky `set3 = set1.setUnion(set2)`.

Comment: In one of your [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63826133/throwing-a-data-exception-if-item-passed-in-array-already-exists) `add` already implements this overflow exception. If you check for duplicates before adding the element then `add` should handle the rest (provided that's still the same code or you want to add this again)

Comment: You should also get in the habit of accepting `const` references when passing potentially large structures like this. You're making copies now all over the place.

Comment: @churill the thing is, I am not adding new numbers from a for to loop to an individual set. I am merging two sets into one and wanting to create an exception capacity error that is thrown if the capacity of the merged set is exceeded (or overflown). Therefore creating a new exception called CapacityExceededError.

Comment: I don't fully understand how this would be different from what `add` did in your previous question. The exception would only be thrown in another place (and have a slightly different name).

Comment: Also: Your merge is flawed: You check for duplicates _after_ adding the item. But at this point `add` would already have thrown a `DuplicateItemError`. You could just use the `contains`-function. (in both cases, I suggest to use `this->contains(...)` in `add` too instead of manual search)

Comment: "I am trying to develop and implement a CapacityErrorException that detects and throws an exception if the unified array set exceeds the capacity amount of the array set" - okay, so I assume you tried something like `if(amount > capacity) throw CapacityErrorException();`? What happened when you tried that?